# Is /data/data always writable?

Tags: android, root

I'm writing an app for rooted Android devices. The app needs to copy files to /data/data.

Is it safe to assume that this partition will always be mounted R/W, or should the app double-check the mount options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal memory containing such folders should always be available as write-able. However, there are no guarantees for SD card with these folders, since the card can be unmounted at any time.

Answer (score 2):

The path /data/data is in internal storage so should never be dismounted.

One thing though, use the methods provided such as `Context.getFilesDir()` to get the correct path to a directory that your app can write to. Don't assume you can write to `/data/data/some/directory` because internal storage has permissions associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

/data/data is always in R/W on rooted devices.  I would do a root check in your app though, just to make sure you don't run into errors.